# Errors when sorting a tableview

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, tableview

Simply put, I have a tableview with a single column which I want to be sorted and stay sorted whenever I add a new item to the observable list.  I've looked at several examples and similar questions online but nothing is working for me.  If I try calling TableView.sort() from the list's change listener, nothing really seems to happen.

When I add the column to the table's sort order that's when things get problematic. Attempting to sort the table after that results in a hard crash of the application. The only error is "Exception in Application start method".  I then moved the sort() call to Platform.runLater() and that prevents the app from crashing. But then a new problem arose.  When calling sort I'll get an array index out of bounds error, which seems to happen at random though I think mostly when the new items exceeds the table's view and needs a scrollbar.

While writing this, I moved the sort out of the change listener and down below into the Task where I'm adding the actual data. No more errors.  So I guess my new question is, why am I having so many issues when attempting to do things from the listener?

```
public class Temp extends Application{


    private ObservableList<String> libraryList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Label statusLabel = new Label("stuff goes here");

        TableView<String> table = new TableView<String>(libraryList);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        TableColumn<String, String> col = new TableColumn<String, String>("Stuff");
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue()));
        table.getColumns().add(col);
        table.getSortOrder().add(col);





        libraryList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
            public void onChanged(Change change) {


                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    table.sort();
                    statusLabel.setText(libraryList.size()+" entries");
                });

            }

        });





        // dummy stuff
        libraryList.add("foo");
        libraryList.add("bar");



        Button b = new Button("Press Me");
        b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                FileTask task = new FileTask();
                new Thread(task).start();
            }
        });


        BorderPane mainBody = new BorderPane();

        mainBody.setTop(statusLabel);
        mainBody.setCenter(table);
        mainBody.setBottom(b);
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainBody);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }








    class FileTask extends Task<Boolean>{

        public FileTask(){

        }


        protected Boolean call() throws Exception{

            Random rand = new Random();
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                String s = ""+rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                libraryList.add(s);
            }

            return true;
        }



    }







    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand the problem now.  When I add an item to the list it calls onChanged(). When I sort the the table, it's also triggering the onChanged thus creating an infinite loop.  I didn't realize the table sorts the data by actually changing the list itself.